# Strange cron behaviour

Tags: linux, iptables, cron

I have a script that reads a list of IPs from a file, compares with the existing ones in a chain, and adds recently added IPs in the file into that chain. Running the script manually (e.g., `./script`) with both root and non-root accounts, returns the expected output. However, running the script in cron has an unexpected behaviour: the already existing IPs in the chain are duplicated.

Here is the cron for the script:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/python /home/user/script
```

Changing the user from `root` to a non-root user does not even execute the script. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: The default PATH for cron is restricted, make sure all the necessary directories for all utilities are included or that you put in the full path to each executable.

Comment: I did it. The strange output remains.

Comment: From which command or file comes this line ?

Comment: /etc/cron.d/script-cron

Comment: Not only is PATH different, but other environment variables may be different or nonexistent, because cron doesn't read in your .bash_profile or .bashrc.

Comment: @Jay does this script take longer than 1 minute to run? If so, your cron entry is running it every minute, and it will run more than once.

Comment: Why are you using an explicit interpreter in cron, but not on the command line?